# Trocar dados do array entre 'S' e 'N'

Tags: jquery, json, array, localstorage

Tenho uma função que irei adaptar para um botão, que irá trocar um dado dentro de um array, entre `S` e `N`.

O código que tenho é:

```
var array = [{"nome":"1","faltou":"N","goleiro":"N","pago":"N"},{"nome":"2","faltou":"N","goleiro":"N","pago":"N"},{"nome":"3","faltou":"N","goleiro":"N","pago":"N"}];


function toggleArrayItem(a, v, d) {
        var i = a.findIndex(function(val){
                return val.nome === v;
            });
    if (i != -1){
      var data = a[i];
            if(d === 'faltou'){
        const isOn = (data.faltou = 'N');
        a[i] = ({"nome":data.nome, "faltou":isOn ? 'N' : 'S', "goleiro":data.goleiro, "pagou":data.pagou});
      } else if(d === 'goleiro'){
        const isOn = data.goleiro = 'N';
        a[i] = ({"nome":data.nome, "faltou":data.faltou, "goleiro":isOn ? 'N' : 'S', "pagou": data.pagou});
      } else if(d === 'pagou'){
        const isOn = data.pagou = 'N';
        a[i] = ({"nome":data.nome, "faltou":data.faltou, "goleiro":data.goleiro, "pagou": isOn ? 'N' : 'S'});
      }
    }
}

toggleArrayItem(array, '1', 'faltou');.
```

Só que não está funcionando corretamente, e queria diminuir o código. Estou usando localStorage em JSON.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem pequenos erros de escrita e lógica que fazem com que o seu código não funcione:

- `const isOn = (data.faltou = 'N');` - Repare que falhou a comparação na parte direita da expressão, e o que você queria fazer era `data.faltou == 'N'` ou até `===` como já tem em alguns locais. Para além disso o próprio valor está invertido pois `isOn` indica se está ligado ou seja se tem `S` mas no seu caso está a apontar para o `N`.
- `, "pagou":data.pagou` - aqui coloca o valor de `data.pagou` que não foi definido no array original e por isso vai apanhar `undefined`. No array original foi definido `pago`

Corrigindo estes pormenores já dá o que espera:

```js
var array = [{
  "nome": "1",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}, {
  "nome": "2",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}, {
  "nome": "3",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}];


function toggleArrayItem(a, v, d) {
  var i = a.findIndex(function(val) {
    return val.nome === v;
  });

  if (i != -1) {
    var data = a[i];
    if (d === 'faltou') {
      const isOn = (data.faltou === 'S');
      a[i] = ({
        "nome": data.nome,
        "faltou": isOn ? 'N' : 'S',
        "goleiro": data.goleiro,
        "pagou": data.pago
      });
    } else if (d === 'goleiro') {
      const isOn = data.goleiro === 'S';
      a[i] = ({
        "nome": data.nome,
        "faltou": data.faltou,
        "goleiro": isOn ? 'N' : 'S',
        "pagou": data.pago
      });
    } else if (d === 'pagou') {
      const isOn = data.pagou === 'N';
      a[i] = ({
        "nome": data.nome,
        "faltou": data.faltou,
        "goleiro": data.goleiro,
        "pagou": isOn ? 'N' : 'S'
      });
    }
  }
}

toggleArrayItem(array, '1', 'faltou');

console.log(array);
```

Quanto à simplificação, pode começar por usar uma [*Arrow Function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) no `findIndex`. Depois para trocar a propriedade desejada não precisa de criar um novo objeto igual apenas com uma propriedade diferente. Pode aceder diretamente pela propriedade que tem e alterar, desde que garanta que faz parte das propriedades que quer permitir alterar:

```js
var array = [{
  "nome": "1",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}, {
  "nome": "2",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}, {
  "nome": "3",
  "faltou": "N",
  "goleiro": "N",
  "pago": "N"
}];


function toggleArrayItem(a, v, d) {
  var i = a.findIndex(val => val.nome === v);  
  if (i != -1 && ['faltou', 'goleiro', 'pagou'].includes(d)) {
    a[i][d] = a[i][d] === 'S' ? 'N' : 'S';
  }
}

toggleArrayItem(array, '1', 'faltou');

console.log(array);
```

Como nota final sugiro nomes melhores para as variaveis. Deixei os nomes iguais aos que tinha para ser mais relacionavel com o seu código original mas `a`, `v` e `d` não são bons nomes e tornam o código complicado de ler

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Isac . Eu tenho quase certeza que essa a Arrow Function não funciona corretamente em apps híbridos em Android 4.4 e 5, mas irei testar e já dou um parecer.

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Sem problema. Se não funcionar é só colocar o `findIndex` como tinha originalmente. Mas desde já digo que é improvável que suporte `findIndex` e não Arrow Functions. Se olhar no [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=Arrow%20Functions) e até no MDN vê que o suporte é muito elevado deixando só de fora o clássico IE.

Comment: Irei testar. No HTML funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: eu sou do tipo de pessoa que gosta de entender o código: poderia me explicar o que faz o .includes(d) no seu código?

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Entender o código todo é sempre o ideal. o `includes` é um [método de Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) que testa se o array contem um elemento. É uma forma de evitar ter de fazer `if (d === 'faltou' || d == 'goleiro' || d === 'pagou')`, que normalmente até fica mais extenso mas no seu caso não ficou tanto porque a variável `d` tem um nome muito curto.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tenho outra sugestão, veja se atende:

```js
 var array = [{
        "nome": "1",
        "faltou": "N",
        "goleiro": "N",
        "pago": "N"
    },
    {
        "nome": "2",
        "faltou": "N",
        "goleiro": "N",
        "pago": "N"
    },
    {
        "nome": "3",
        "faltou": "N",
        "goleiro": "N",
        "pago": "N"
    }];


    function toggleArrayItem(a, v, d) {

        a.forEach(item => {
            if (item.nome == v) {
                for (var prop in item) {
                    if (prop == d) {
                        item[prop]=item[prop] == 'S' ? 'N' : 'S';
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(a);
    }

    toggleArrayItem(array, '1', 'faltou');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição @AdjairCosta! Irei dar uma entendida no código também!